# Ruby File.open not creating file

Tags: ruby, file, io, writetofile

I'm trying to create and write to a new file using

```
@logFile = File.open("C:\Users\---\Desktop\mylog.log", "w+")
```

And nothing happens. My program uses

```
  @logFile.write ("Hello")
  @logFile.flush
```

And this line seems to be running ok (no crashes or anything)
But i can't see any newly created file.

What am i missing out here?

Comment: See the opening section in the [IO documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html), along with the [Strings section](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) in the Literals documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your backslashes are escaped, in a string enclosed with double quotes you need to double them, or just use the Unix notation.
   So `"C:\\Users\\---\\Desktop\\mylog.log"`

or `"C:/Users/---/Desktop/mylog.log"`

or `'C:\Users\---\Desktop\mylog.log'`

2. Paths in Ruby are safest in Unix notation, so even when you use backslashes for ease of copying you are better to convert them to Unix formatting.

like this `'C:\Users\---\Desktop\mylog.log'.gsub('\\','/')`

The double backslash is also needed here, the ' and \ need to be escaped using single quotes.

Another tip not relevant tot the question but very handy: use the block method to open a file so that it is clear when the file is closed, see this example

```
File.open(path, 'w') do |file|
  file.puts "Hello"
end
```

The file is closed after the end.

For logging though, take a look at [logger](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html), once you used it you won't stop using it.

Comment: By the way: I believe, there *should* actually now be a file named `Users---Desktopmylog.log` in whatever the working directory of the `C:` drive was, when you ran your script, created by the original buggy version of your code. It's been a long time since I have done any Windows programming, though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: yes, hence no error, in such case a search with everything.exe would reveal where mylog.log is residing and had make the mistake obvious

Comment: "All paths in Ruby need to be in Unix notation". No, they don't. On Windows a Windows-style path is fine. Depending on how the string is defined the delimiters might need to be escaped. This is covered in the opening to the [IO documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html). *nix-style delimiters are more convenient, and allow Ruby to translate between Windows and *nix systems transparently, but they're not required.

Comment: true, but as a windows ruby dev I encountered lots of problems in the past using windows style paths and so took on the habbit of using unix style paths, support for windows is defentitly rising the last years, I'll adapt my answer

Comment: You should use `path = File.join("C:","Program Files","Blah")` to create paths

Answer (score -1):

You should always use `path = File.join("C:","Program Files","Blah")`
To ensure it works on any architecture.

Comment: This will fail on *nix, which has no idea of "C:".

Comment: I guess the point of my post was that you should always use `File.join()` to generate nested paths rather than strings.